# function.bind() not supported in IE8. make it available specifically for IE8 browsers? or keep it generic

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

I am using function.bind() in JS which is not supported in IE8 so I included below code to make it work. (referred from StackOverflow answer)

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
      Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
        if (typeof this !== 'function') {
          // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
          // internal IsCallable function
          throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what     is     trying to be bound is not callable');
        }

        var aArgs   = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
            fToBind = this,
            fNOP    = function() {},
            fBound  = function() {
              return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP && oThis
                     ? this
                     : oThis,
                     aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
            };

        fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
        fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

        return fBound;
      };
}
```

Keeping this script code for all browser will it make other browser such as IE11 slower? (which supports bind)

Comment: *"will it make other browser such as IE11 slower?"* - Yes. It *is* more code to download, and then there's an if statement that wouldn't otherwise be executed. But I doubt you'd be able to tell the difference.

Comment: If what you're wondering is "will this replace the native, faster implementation of Function.bind() in newer browsers?" then the answer is no - this script (known as a _polyfill_) only defines .bind() when an implementation doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @nnnnnn Im still unclear how this script does the trick to help IE8 support .bind() function.  That is where Im having dificult time to analyse. I tried loading this script specific to browser. But it is giving some issues with that. I am reading into feature detection for ultimate solution. If I load above script on first page of application will that stop executing this script code for subsequent .bind() calls?

Comment: @voithos yes that is exactly what i wanted to know. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you for this inspiration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only drawback when running this code in a browser that already has `.bind()` is the little bit of extra code to download.  When this code runs in a modern browser, it hits the first `if` statement and skips everything else.  If `.bind()` is already supported, then this polyfill does not replace the existing functionality.  It sees that the existing functionality is already present so it does nothing.

Polyfills like this are great to use.  They let you code for modern browsers (rather than least common denominator) while still supporting older browsers.  Good polyfills like this are highly recommended.

---

It sounds like you're unclear how this script works.  What it does is the following:

1. It checks to see if `.bind()` is already available on functions.  If it is, then the script does nothing as it skips all the rest of its code.  This is what happens in modern browsers.  So, only the first `if` statement executes in a modern browser.
2. If `.bind()` is not present, then it adds a property named `bind` to the `Function` prototype so it will be available on all function objects and assigns a function to that property.  And, that function implements the standard `.bind()` behavior.  Now, all function objects in your code will have a `.bind()` property no matter which browser they are running in.

Comment: right now this script is downloaded on all browsers on first load of the page. Does first IF condition gets executed on script load only and functions get support for .bind() or Script gets downloaded and each time there is fn.bind() call it will check for IF condition if .bin() is not supported for that browser? Just to get clear idea of it.

Comment: @pratikwebdev - Your script runs only once when it is first loaded. That one time, it checks to see if `.bind()` is already present or whether it should add a polyfill implementation.